# UITableViewCell Subclassing results in Storyboard error?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a strange error that is happening when I attempt to run my project. I am redesigning my old setup, which was a dedicated UITableViewController. I am moving that into a standard UIViewController with a UITableView inside of it.

I am getting this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

I narrowed down exactly what is causing it, but I have no idea why. It happens when I attempt to set the UITableViewCell within the tableview to be a custom UITableViewCell class that I created. Keep in mind that I used the exact same setup for my original UITableViewController. Why is the build failing with a Storyboard compiler error because I set the UITableViewCell to be a custom subclass?

EDIT 1 to add relevant code:

.h

```
@interface SingleCodeViewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>


@end
```

.m

```
@interface SingleCodeViewController ()

// Connected to the table view in IB
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation SingleCodeViewController


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 30)];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 30)];


    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            label.text = @"Date";
            break;
        case 1:
            label.text = @"Rate";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);

    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [view addSubview:label];


    return view;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0;
}

// Sets the background for each static cell to be the same custom cell as the table view's.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CodeCellTVC class]]) {
        if (![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CustomCellBackground class]]) {
            cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

My custom UITableViewCell class:

.h

```
@interface CodeCellTVC : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *codeTableLabel;

@end
```

.m

```
// Empty implementation
```

Comment: Are you sure that everything is linked up properly.  Meaning all connections are made between the controller and your `UITableViewCell`.  Also, can you please add relevant code?

Comment: @EvanStoddard I am doing the view strictly in IB. So setting the custom class for the UITableViewCell is done there as well. I added some relevant code that is apart of the connected UIVieController.

Comment: The class that you are trying to link your `UITableViewCell` to is not a subclass of the `UITableViewCell` class so therefore it will crash.

Comment: @EvanStoddard That code is for the entire UIViewController. I have added code to the specific UITableViewCell class that I am attempting to link my cell's to.

Comment: Well you also need to have a `UITableViewController` class in order to use a `UITableView`.  Please show to code relevant to the `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @EvanStoddard I have added the code for the UITableViewCell. It is nothing special because it just adds a UILabel. Can't I setup a UITableView outlet like I have and use the appropriate tableview methods instead of creating another class as a UITableViewController?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37214/discussion-between-jonathan-and-evan-stoddard)

Comment: Yes but you need make your view controller a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`